# How do I change Ubuntu to Lubuntu installation?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, lubuntu

I have loaded Ubuntu 15.10 in place of Windows XP, but it is slow and hangs.

The laptop i have has Celeron M380 1.4Ghz 1GB ram and 160GB HDD. I would like to change to the lighter Lubuntu for a smoother operation, but I don't know how to do this.

I installed Ubuntu from a bootable disk but don't have a disk of Lubuntu so will have to download. What is the simplest method?

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/243318/how-to-install-lubuntu-desktop-environment-and-only-the-desktop-environment

Comment: The simplest method is to crate a backup copy of your personal files (on external media) and reinstall the operation system.

Answer (score 1):

I would just install the Lubuntu desktop:

```
sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

Then log out. On the login-screen where you write your username, there is a little ubuntu symbol in the corner. Klick it and choose a login-option that looks like Lubuntu. Log in with your usual details. Your system should run fine on this and you still have everything that you installed.