# Why Firefox crashes when using it while working with Gimp?

Tags: 18.04, firefox, gimp

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04.1 and Gimp 2.10 and Firefox is updated to its last version Mozilla Firefox 62.0.3

I have a serious issue, while I am working on a photo edition using Gimp, and then I open two or more tabs, suddenly my screen freeze or Firefox crashes.

What can I do to avoid this?

Is is due to I use only one work-space?
Is it a memory issue?

I show you here my free -m out put while I am using gimp and Firefox and brave all together...

```
 free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1984        1572          99         143         312         110
Swap:          2047         469        1578
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Is it a memory issue?", you tell. are you running out of memory and swap that OOM kill is running?

Comment: I don't think so, I will edit my question posting my memory output while I am using both gimp and firefox and hope it helps...

Comment: you only have 2G ram? that might be an issue, on top of that you're on a 64bit os. you might consider using a 32bit OS. Ubuntu 18 doesn't come in 32 bit version, might need to use other flavors (mate, lubuntu, xubuntu, budgie)

Comment: With only 2G ram, you should consider [installing `lubuntu-desktop`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243318/how-to-install-lubuntu-desktop-environment-and-only-the-desktop-environment). See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) for more information.

Comment: Well, my system is only 2GB Ram but thats the minimum required for ubuntu 18.04 and also for Lubuntu, so I don't think that is the issue here and why Lubuntu will be better than Ubuntu?

Comment: Lubuntu isn't better, it's lighter, therefore *better* for your very limited hardware.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia My hardware may be very limited but your kindness is much more limited... Thanks for your very enlarge expertise...

Comment: More useful than `free -m` maybe to run `top -o MEM%`. Since your system has started using `swap` you can expect problems. All three programs, Firefox, GIMP, and the Brave browser will use a lot of RAM. I suggest you don't use any other program while you're working in GIMP as far as possible. That may make things better.